# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of concat()

Tags: xslt, concatenation

The below xsl works fine if I do not bring in the "other_location_postal_code" field, which is commented here.

This is because there are multiple records if I bring in that field.

How can I have this xsl evaluate each record so it would write this record twice, once for the one "other location postal code" and the other?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" xmlns:fct="http://www.taleo.com/xsl_functions" exclude-result-prefixes="e fct">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:param name="OUTBOUND_FOLDER"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <source>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:Requisition"/>
    </source>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="e:Requisition">
    <xsl:variable name="job_id" select="e:ContestNumber"/>
    <xsl:variable name="other_location_postal_code" select="e:JobInformation/e:JobInformation/e:OtherLocations/e:Location/e:NetworkLocation/e:NetworkLocation/e:ZipCode"/>
    <job>
      <job_id>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;','![CDATA[',$job_id,']]','&gt;')"/>
      </job_id>
      <other_location_postal_code>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('![CDATA[',$other_location_postal_code,']]')"/>
      </other_location_postal_code>
      </job>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want it to come out like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<source>
<job>
<job_id><![CDATA[15000005]]></job_id>
<other_location_postal_code><![CDATA[77382]]></other_location_postal_code>
</job>
<job>
<job_id><![CDATA[15000005]]></job_id>
<other_location_postal_code><![CDATA[37567]]></other_location_postal_code>
</job>
</source>
```

The initial XML looks like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    -<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   -<soapenv:Body>
   -<ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   -<Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
   -<Attributes>
    <Attribute name="count">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.088</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="entity">Requisition</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="mode">T-XML</Attribute>
    <Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    -<Content>
   -<ExportTXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01">
   -<e:Requisition>
    <e:ContestNumber>15000005</e:ContestNumber>
    -<e:JobInformation>
   -<e:JobInformation>
   -<e:OtherLocations>
   -<e:Location>
    <e:ZipCode>77002</e:ZipCode>
    </e:Location>
   -<e:Location>
    <e:ZipCode>77050</e:ZipCode>
    </e:Location>
    </e:OtherLocations>
    </e:JobInformation>
    </e:JobInformation>
    </e:Requisition>
    </ExportTXML>
    </Content>
    </Document>
    </ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When dealing with XSLT, please provide an input, the XSLT and a desired output.

Comment: Also please minimize your code to only what's necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message simply says that an argument to the `concat` function is a sequence of more than one node. So some of your variable selects two or more nodes and concat expects as single node for each of its arguments. You will need to decide what you want to output, either only the first node with `$var[1]` or the concatenation with `string-join($var, ' ')`.

Note that you don't need all those attempts to output CDATA section, you can tell the XSLT processor the `cdata-section-elements` on the `xsl:output` direction.

As you have now posted more details here is one suggestion to map each `ZipCode` element to `job` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01"
  exclude-result-prefixes="e">

<xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="job_id other_location_postal_code"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <source>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:OtherLocations/e:Location/e:ZipCode"/>
  </source>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:ZipCode">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::e:Requisition">
    <xsl:with-param name="zc" select="current()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e:Requisition">
  <xsl:param name="zc"/>
  <job>
    <job_id><xsl:value-of select="e:ContestNumber"/></job_id>
    <other_location_postal_code><xsl:value-of select="$zc"/></other_location_postal_code>
  </job>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am actually trying to have it write both records separately like so:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<source>
-<job>
<title><![CDATA[ Residential Driver ]]></title>
<location_city><![CDATA[Houston]]></location_city>
<location_state><![CDATA[TX]]></location_state>
<location_postal_code><![CDATA[77001]]></location_postal_code>
<location_country><![CDATA[US]]></location_country>
<job_id><![CDATA[15000005]]></job_id>
</job>
</source>

Comment: Sorry it keeps not letting me hit enter LOL.  I need it to write the record twice once for postal code 1 and second for the second postal code.  So it would be two job sections.  I will try to figure out the cdata thing too.

Comment: We need to see the input XML structure as well and an explanation which of the elements in the input you want to map to a `job` in the output.

Comment: I tried <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" cdata-section-elements="title"/> it put the cdata sections around the one title field.  Do I need to name out every field for it to do it?  Also, it moved it from being on one line to three lines was like so <title><CDATA[Stuff]]></title> to now the title header and footer are on their own lines.

Comment: Figured out how to do to each field but still wondering about how to keep it on one line.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please raise the CDATA question as a separate question. Mixing two unrelated problems in one entry doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Yes sorry CDATA portion I am not as worried about.  Getting the two separate records is my main issue.  I know the database side but this side is new to me :)

Comment: Martin - Awesome!  That worked :)  So if I want to add more fields than just ZipCode.  Like Country,Name and State,Name how would I add those two fields into that same mix?

Comment: Either add the literal result elements with an `xsl:value-of` and the proper XPath expression for the content yourself or edit your question and show us the elements in the input sample and the wanted result sample.

Comment: The path would be <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:OtherLocations/e:Location/e:Country/e:Name"/> and <xsl:apply-templates select="//e:OtherLocations/e:Location/e:State/e:Name"/> so on the ZipCode one you called the template match "e:ZipCode" what would I call the template for the Country and the State Name fields?  Or are you saying since I am already pulling the Zip Codes that they will already be distinct to the Zip Code record anyway and I can just pull them like normal?

Comment: The `apply-templates` is done once to map an element in your input to one in your wanted output so I don't think you want more `apply-templates`. If there are more items to be output inside a `job` then you can create them as literal result elements and use `xsl:value-of` to output them. It might be easier to make a different element the context node of the template (e.g. `e:Location`) to have shorter paths but as I said, if you can't figure that out yourself then please edit the samples in your question to show the data you have and the corresponding output you want.

Comment: I will give it a shot :)  I really appreciate the help!  This has been very very helpful.